# Organising code in Specflow steps

Tags: specflow

I understand from [Techtalk](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings) that coupling step definitions to features is an anti-pattern.
However I am wondering how to organise my step definitions so that I can easily see in the code what steps go together.

For example should I create a code file for each Feature and a separate file for steps that are shared? or should I have a code file for a set of features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to organize step definitions in a couple of ways, depending on how big the step definition files get.

**Separate data and UI steps**

I have lots of `Given some thing exists in the database` steps, so I usually throw these into a file call DataSteps.cs. I also have lots of `Then something exists in the database` steps and those go into DataAssertionSteps.cs.

All of my `When I fill in some form field` steps go in FormSteps.cs. Anytime I need `Then something in the form is enabled|disabled` or asserting that form fields have a certain value, I throw those into FormPresentationSteps.cs.

**Separate Steps by Model**

Sometimes my step definition files get very large, and I start moving step definitions into files related to a certain model. Say I have a `Person` model. I might create a PersonSteps.cs file that is split into three regions:

```
[Binding]
public class PersonSteps
{
    #region Given
    // Given a person exists with the following attributes:

    #endregion

    #region When
    // When something something about a Person
    #endregion

    #region Then
    // Then a person should exist with the following attributes:
    #endregion
}
```

Basically I start out with these files:

- DataSteps.cs - The `Given`s for setting up test data
- DataAssertionSteps.cs - The `Then`s for asserting that data exists correctly in the database
- PresentationAssertionSteps.cs - Just general stuff making sure the UI looks as itshould
- FormSteps.cs - Steps for manipulating forms
- FormPresentationAssertionSteps.cs - Making sure form fields have the proper values, are enabled/disabled correctly. Validation messages show up, etc.
- GeneralSteps.cs - A poorily named catch-all for stuff that doesn't fit in the above files. Maybe I should rename it "AndIShallCallItSomethingManagerSteps.cs"?

Comment: I am intrigued that you are testing forms. We have been trying hard to keep forms out of our test code. I would write a can you tell me more question if I could figure out how to word it.

Comment: Here's the short version of my answer. We use the Microsoft WebForms framework for building our site. It's a crappy framework to begin with (though it was among the best when it first came out). On top of that, take _every_ best practice in software engineering that you know of and don't do that. Basically, the three most common keys that we use are `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v`. Because of that business logic is mixed up in JavaScript and C#, and copied and pasted across dozens of files. So all forms get brutally tested (even down to form field max lengths and email address formats).

Comment: Thank you @gregburghardt for your brutal honesty :-)

Comment: I like the approach you are taking to organise your step definitions. However, what is the difference between steps found in "DataAssertionSteps.cs" and "PresentationAssertionSteps.cs"? Aren't the step definition found in these files asserting data presented to the user via a webpage? If so why not just have "PresentationAssertionSteps.cs"?

Comment: DataAssertionSteps is focused on the database, whereas PresentationAssertionSteps is focused on the user interface. Just a way to help cut down on the number of lines of code in each step definition file, plus make step definitions more findable.